# postfix not routing mail to remote hosts

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to setup postfix to be able to send/receive mail, I'm able to receive messages, but when I send to any other domain other than my domain name which is setup in postfix, I get the following error:

```
Jun 12 12:25:03 DEMISED postfix/smtpd[32291]: warning: hostname IN-213-226-141-251.somehost.com does not resolve to address 213.226.141.251: Name or service not known
Jun 12 12:25:03 DEMISED postfix/smtpd[32291]: connect from unknown[213.226.141.251]
Jun 12 12:25:06 DEMISED postfix/smtpd[32291]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[213.226.141.251]: 554 5.7.1 <*******@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<k@d****.net> to=<*****@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[10.49.177.2]>
Jun 12 12:25:07 DEMISED postfix/smtpd[32291]: disconnect from unknown[213.226.141.251]
```

My `main.conf`:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination
myhostname = demised.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
mydestination = demised.net, gitlab, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
```

I want to be able to send email to any domain, not just my domain, how can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination`

With

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

this is ONE LINE by the way

And Comment like this

```
#smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
```

With

in main.cf

Comment: @user3578847 use this path to determine FIRST what each of the the config parameters are set to default, then after that make sure you apply as is necessary to secure you from what attacks can affect you http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html. In this case, you want to know what `#smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain` will open you out to (I mean SMTP server spamming` and see what value of `smtpd_sender_restrictions` or a combination of it and others that can leave you at your desired security level. You welcome!